# Fixed width responsive carousel

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm struggling to style a widget.

The idea is that I have 5 content sections, all laid out in a row using flexbox and the same width.

In other words, a fixed width carousel without setting a specific width.

What I'd like to do is constrain the parent container to the width of a single item so as to show just one item at a time. Then I'll use a button to navigate through the items. However, I'm struggling to work how to achieve it - if it can be achieved at all.

Obviously I could set a fixed max width on the parent but that wouldn't be dynamic and I don't want to leave it unbound because it looks bad on large screens.

As you will see when running the example, the items are not currently the same width.

Setting `flex 0 0 100%`, sets each item to 100% of the entire (scrollable) width, 20% doesn't work either.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.container {
}
.scrollable {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.item {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  height: 100px;
}
.item:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.item:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: magenta;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="scrollable">
      <div class="item">this is item 1</div>
      <div class="item">item 2</div>
      <div class="item">this is item 3</div>
      <div class="item">item 4</div>
      <div class="item">this is item 5</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How do you expect to give all the items the same width if the content difference and you're not able to set a static width?

Answer (score 0):

Set your item class with pixels.. you will have the same width then..

```
.item {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: I will but it's not then dynamic.

Comment: Explain to me what you want to do? Exactly

Comment: I'm trying to shrink-wrap the parent to the width of an item. Obviously I need to be able to make the items the same width too.

Comment: I make an fiddle for you check if that what you need: https://jsfiddle.net/Mohcinbn/ps59gfL4/11/

Comment: No sorry. If the widest content is say, 428px, I want to make all items that width, and then constrain the parent to that width so that only one item can be seen at a time. I could set the parent width to a largish max-width but it results in lots of white space on each side, which isn't nice.

Answer (score 0):

simply `width:100%`

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.container {
}
.scrollable {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
.item {
  width:100%;
  flex-shrink:0;
  height: 100px;
}
.item:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.item:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: magenta;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="scrollable">
      <div class="item">this is item 1</div>
      <div class="item">item 2</div>
      <div class="item">this is item 3</div>
      <div class="item">item 4</div>
      <div class="item">this is item 5</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```